# Sudo access using AD without using FQDN

Tags: sudo, active-directory

I've been able to get my server setup where it will allow me to use my AD credentials to login, and sudo works as well, but only if I sign in using  `myuser@mydomain.com`.

I changed the `/etc/sssd/sssd/conf` file `use_fully_qualified_names = False` and I can login with the same user `myuser` without the FQDN, but it won't allow me to sudo when logged in that way. What am I missing here?